# Bash join ls output

Tags: bash

How can I join 2 ls results ? 
- I need this because the files are in 2 different directories and I need to sort them in different ways.

Anyway for the output I need a normal listing with both results.

Answer (score 6):

No need to run `ls` twice, just put multiple file specifications as arguments.

```
ls /path/to/first_file_spec* /different_path/to/second_file_spec*
```

Comment: What would be if you needed to use different switches for each `ls`?

Answer (score 2):

```
(ls <first dir>; ls <second dir>) | sort ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
{ ls folder1 && ls folder2; }
```

Got this from:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=803748

Try this example:

```
{ ls /etc/fonts && ls /etc/init; }|while read i; do echo $i; done
```

(hope you have these folders - replace if you don't).

Comment: No reason, just a habit of not running the second command if the first fails.

Comment: @Benoit: It's a very very good habit; while it doesn't matter much in this case, it's quite possible for a later command to do some very strange unexpected things after a first command fails.

Comment: I know it is a good habit to use `&&` when appropriate. But here it does not seem to be particularly indicated…

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `find` is more useful here because of that "directory:" format that `ls` uses when it's given more than one directory as an argument.

```
find /etc/dpkg/ /etc/apt -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | sort
```

You can customize output if your find supports printf, for example

```
find /etc/dpkg/ /etc/apt -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%f\n" | sort
```